# LWC jest test on conditional element

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-dom, lwc-jest

How can I test if:true element in my lwc? showLoadingSpinner is @api. I am new to jest, sorry if stupid question. Console log shows null.

```
<template if:true={showLoadingSpinner}>
    <div id="spinner">
        <lightning-spinner class="slds-align_absolute-center" variant="brand" size="small" alternative-text="Loading.."></lightning-spinner>
    </div>
</template>
```

test.js

```
const element = createElement('c-pagerLwc', { is: page });
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.showLoadingSpinner = true;


        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            let spinner = document.querySelector('#spinner');
            console.log('spinner: ' + spinner);
            expect(spinner).not.toBeNull();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write the jest test for conditional rendering as below. Some important things to considered:-

- You need to import your component and use [describe](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#describename-fn) which creates a block that groups together several related tests.
- [afterEach](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#aftereachfn-timeout) Runs a function after each one of the tests in this file completes. If the function returns a promise or is a generator, Jest waits for that promise to resolve before continuing.
- [it](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout) - All you need in a test file is the test method which runs a test.
- [Expect](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect) - When you're writing tests, you often need to check that values meet certain conditions. expect gives you access to a number of "matchers" that let you validate different things.
- A lot of examples are avialable in this [github repository for lwc](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes)

I have just added the code when spinner does not exist in dom, You can add another test in test file for testing the positive scenario.

---

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import HelloConditionalRendering from 'c/pagerLwc';

describe('c-pager-lwc', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    it('does not show spinner by default', () => {
        // Create element
        const element = createElement('c-pager-lwc', {
            is: HelloConditionalRendering
        });
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        // Verify spinner exist
        const detailEl = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('lightning-spinner');
        expect(detailEl).toBe(null);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works and git rep is awesome.